# how do you pass javascript variables into php to update a table

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following php code with a form which updates a table. However I want to add a javascript variable to the sql so that the variable will be added to a column in the database. 
The variable is in a different file to the php.

php :=

```
$name = $_POST['firstname'];
 $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
 $userAddress = $_POST['address'];
 $userPostCode = $_POST['postcode'];
 $delivery = $_POST['deliverytype'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, ADDRESS, POST_CODE, DELIVERY_TYPE) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$userAddress', '$userPostCode', '$delivery') ";
 $conn->exec($sql);
```

i then want to add to that a totalcost variable from the following javascript that will go in `Total_Order_Cost` and `$totalCost`

here is the js function that i wish to take the variable `totalPrice` from

```
function displayBasket(){

  basket = document.getElementById("basket"); 
  string = "";
  var basketStorage = localStorage.getItem("basket"); 
  jsonBasket = JSON.parse(basketStorage); 

    var totalPrice = 0;
    itemTotal = 0;
  for (var property in jsonBasket){ 

    var qPrice = jsonBasket[property ].quantity * jsonBasket[property ].cost;
    var total = jsonBasket[property ].quantity;
    string += "<section id='basketPageSection'>";
    if(jsonBasket.hasOwnProperty(property )){ 
      string += "<p>Item: " + jsonBasket[property ].name + "</p>"; 
      string += "<p>Price: £" + jsonBasket[property ].cost + "</p>"; 
      string += "<p>Quantity: " + jsonBasket[property ].quantity + "</p>"; 

    }

    totalPrice += qPrice;
    itemTotal += total;
    string += "</section>";

  }

  string += "<section id='basketSection'> <h3> Total Cost: £" + parseFloat(totalPrice).toFixed(2) + "</h3></section>"

  basket.innerHTML = string; 
  displayQuant();
}
```

Comment: Notice: Your code is vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. Have a look at `Prepared Statements`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hidden input field change it value attribute and submit along with rest of the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="calc" id="calc" value="">
```

Use Jquery to set its value

```
$('#calc').val(someval);
```

Update Javascript

```
document.getElementById("calc").value="Your Value";
```

Comment: where do i add this to my code? To the form? I am new o JQuery

Comment: You could use plain javascript as well let me update my answer

Comment: okay, i see what you are doing, where do i put the form though? with my forms in the form file? @AAB

Comment: you mean the input field rite Yes it should be placed inside the form tag you wish to submit

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax.

It is the best solution for me :

Use a code like that in your javascript :

```
value1= ... ; // firstname
value2= ... ; // lastname    
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: 'firstname='+value1+'&lastname='+value2+'&address= ....,
        success: function () {
          alert('data sent');
        }
      });
```

> Another Way

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('#formID').serialize()+"&extraval=1&extraval2=2...",
            success: function () {
              alert('data sent');
            }
          });
```